# Importing utf-8 encoded data from csv to SQL Server using bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, csv, utf-8, bulkinsert, bcp

I am trying to import raw data that I have in `.csv` format to my table in SQL Server. My table is called `[raw].[sub_brand_channel_mapping]`.

[image]

The last column `ImportFileId` is generated by my python code. I first set all the rows of that column as the default value generated. Then I use bulk insert to import my csv data in utf-8 format to my table in SQL Server. However, during the process a lot of special characters are changing. I am using a format file like this

```
10.0
8
1      SQLCHAR            0       100      "\t"     1    sub_brand_id                          ""
2      SQLCHAR            0       1024     "\t"     2    sub_brand_name                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                      
3      SQLCHAR            0       100      "\t"     3    channel_country_id                    ""
4      SQLCHAR            0       1024     "\t"     4    channel_id                            ""
5      SQLCHAR            0       1024     "\t"     5    channel_name                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6      SQLCHAR            0       256      "\t"     6    status                                ""
7      SQLCHAR            0       256      "\t"     7    eff_start_date                        ""
8      SQLCHAR            0       256      "\r\n"   8    eff_end_date                          ""
```

My bulk insert command looks like this:

```
bcp "{table}" in "{file}" {connect_string} -f {format_file} -F {first_row} -    b 10000000 -e {error_file} -q -m {max_errors}
```

My csv files have "\t" as the delimiter. I need to import the exact names without any change. What should I do ?

P.S. I did try converting my utf-8 encoded csv to utf-16-le and then use "-w" in my bcp command. It is giving a lot of errors. In short it didn't work. Please advise me on how to do this.